# App doesn't receive push notifications in background mode

Tags: ios, background, push-notification

I'm developing an iOS app that receives well the remote notification when it is in the running state, but it doesn't receive any thing and the notification banner is not showing up in the background state. I set notification stale to banner, background fetch and remote notification are checked in the background modes menu, I'm using xcode 6 and `didReceiveRemoteNotification` to handle the notification.
Any ideas on how to fix this issu please ?

Answer (score 0):

Check if Background App Refresh is enabled for your application.
Then check what callback method you're using, this must be

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler:
```